Why if there is no main disk found does the installer point to the ubuntu installer drive? This should be filtered out
I just ran an ubuntu 24.04 install on a machine and I think the NVME was not recognized (which was 16GB) and my flash drive was 16GB.  So I assumed all was well.  As soon as I told the installer to install the OS it was an immediate failure and something about too many symbolic links deep.  It tried to submit to the developers, but took too long so I shut down the machine.  Then could not for the life of me understand why it wouldnt boot into ubuntu again for try number two.
I plug the USB back into windows and it was unformatted according to the windows popup.  The machine BIOS was working fine as a windows 11 boot disk worked just fine.
So I am using Rufus to rebuild my USB bootable image again and inspecting closer when formatting that my USB external is not the source of installing my OS.
Can we add code that somehow doesnt let the source USB drive be installed in which is already mounted with the installer files?  I confirmed twice this is what happens when I put in a broken nvme and the only disk is the usb drive.

You mention the release (24.04) but don't provide details as to what installer you attempted to use (ie. subiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer and calamares are available for 24.04 selected by product/ISO you download which you don't mention). How you write the ISO to media can influence the installer; you do mention an app that allows you to reformat the ISO which can adversely impact installer if you don't match ISO write options with your hardware too. A simple clone of ISO to install media is what is expected by installer (not reformatted by operator during ISO write)
